# How to call a lua function in neovim from autocommand or user_command

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm trying to migrate some old vimscript to lua.   I have a bunch of settings for 'prose' and now have these in .config/nvim/plugin/functions.lua as:

```
function prose()
vim.o.fdo:append('search')
vim.bo.virtualedit = block
-- more commands
end
```

Then in prose.lua:

`````
local textedit = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('textedit', {clear = true})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufEnter", "BufNew"}, {
  group = "textedit",
  pattern = {"*.adoc", "*.md", "*.tex"},
  callback = "prose",
})

vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
  'Prose',
  "call prose()",
  {nargs = 0, desc = 'Apply prose settings'}
)````

But either the autocommand on opening an .adoc file or running :Prose on the command line will return:
 
````E117: Unknown function: prose````

How can I make my 'prose' function available?
`````

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on Icheylus's reply.

By assigning the callback like this

```lua
callback = require('functions').prose()
```

You are trying to assign the output of the function to the callback. This would work if your function returned a function, but your function returns nothing.

Thus a simple tweak is to just remove the `()`

```lua
callback = require('functions').prose
```

Or you could even create your function if it is really simple right in the callback of the autocommand.

```lua
local textedit = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('textedit', {clear = true})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufEnter", "BufNew"}, {
  group = "textedit",
  pattern = {"*.adoc", "*.md", "*.tex"},
  callback = function()
      vim.o.fdo:append('search')
      vim.bo.virtualedit = block
      -- more commands
  end,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

First, your `functions.lua` file must be in `.config/nvim/lua/` directory.

For your autocommand, modify callback to require `functions.lua` and function `prose`:

```lua
callback = require('functions').prose()
```

For your user command:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Prose', function()
    require('functions').prose()
  end,                                                                                                                                  
  {nargs = 0, desc = 'Apply prose settings'}                                                                                                       
)
```

Comment: I moved the single 'function prose()' to lua/functions2.lua  and changed the callback to:  ````callback = require('functions2').prose()````.    But then I get:  ````lua/prose.lua:21: attempt to index a boolean value````.  Some other functions set ```` M = {}``` and ```` return M````, but trying that produces ````lua/prose.lua:21: attempt to call field 'prose' (a nil value)````

Comment: If you want some help, edit your first post to add full code of `lua/prose.lua`. We need to see line 21 to understand your error.